# Dealing with more than 100k categories in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, development

In shop that i'm developing I need to deal with more than 100k categories. 
The problem is with displaying them in adminpanel especially in sites: "catalog/categories/index or edit" and "catalog/products/edit/". It took more than 4 GB of RAM when I opened these pages with `memory_limit = -1`

I would like to know why Magento takes that much RAM in admin panel if in storefront it lasts only few seconds to load all categories. Even if I remove category tree and all other blocks for editing on site "catalog/categories/index or edit" it doesn't help and it still takes a lot of ram.

What is the best way to deal with such a large number of categories?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Magento 2 are you on?

We have some known issues around performance/memory usage of admin/category activities that we're working on as we speak for the next release (2.2) with many of them already checked in.

If you're on mainline - does that help address you needs?